# is it possible to use the firebase extension "Delete User Data" in flutter code

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-extensions

I have a "Delete my account and all data" button in my app.
Is it possible to use the firebase extension "Delete User Data" for this?

this firebase extension: https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/delete-user-data

I can't finde a code example, it seems to me it's only for use in the firebase console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension documentation says at the beginning:

> Use this extension to automatically delete certain data keyed on a user ID when the user is deleted from Firebase Authentication.

This means **any** time a user account is deleted in Firebase Auth. That could be manual deletion, or if you allow the user to delete their own account.  No code sample is required - any deletion of user account applies through any one of the many SDKs and APIs provided that can do it.

If that's what you're trying to do, then this seems helpful.